# How to update app

Tags: android, ios, web-services, push-notification

I want to update the content in my mobile apps when data is updated on the server. Right now our apps only gets updated content when the user opens the app, so if there is a big update with lots of pictures the user will have to wait for content to download before it can be browsed. I want to push immediately so the user (almost) never have to wait for the download to complete because everything will be pushed immediately from server to app.

We ensure that the user has the right version of data with a revision system, that makes the app capable of comparing downloaded version of texts and photos with latest version on server.

I think special push messages can do the trick. When something is updated in the backend we can send a special push message to the app that will trigger the app to go and have a look for new  content in the server. Has anybody been using this architecture? Or alternatively architecture that will ensure that my use case about immediate pushing data is accomplished. Thanks.

/Claus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to get INSTANT notification when your app is not running.

Push notifications have an inherent lag. It's my understanding that they usually get delivered within 10-15 minutes of being sent.

That's what you want to do. Have your server send a push to your client apps when an update is available. When your app receives a push, it should ask for background time, then poll the server to see if it needs the update, and start a background download if yes. You'll want to end the background session once you've started the `NSURLSession`.

You can use a background `NSURLSession` to run the download in the background. If you do that then the download will continue and finish even if your app gets terminated, and the OS will re-launch your app and notify you when the download is complete.

This stuff is pretty well documented. I was able to work out how to use it by looking at the docs in Xcode and doing a little experimenting.

Comment: How did you implement that the push messages trigger the download? One idea is that we generate a special message (e.g. with text:  Content updated) that the app will recognize and trigger that the app go to the server. Is that the way you implemented this? Or is there some special type of ‘system’ push messages that is designed for interacting with the app?

Comment: You want to set up your app for silent push notifications. That causes the system to send a message to your app when the push notification is received. That is basically just a poke, telling you to check for new data. You'd then ask for background time, check your server for updated content, and use NSURLSession to start a download if there is new content to be downloaded.

Comment: I did a google search and found this link on silent push notifications. Seems pretty good: http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

Push notification can't contain much data. But you can encourage users to launch the app and so download data.

However, I never tried but may be there is a way on Android when `onMessageReceived()` is called, to do something, like download latest data. It's just an idea.